# Use more than one about.me address

Tags: links, about-me

I would like to be able to use two different [about.me](https://about.me/) addresses. One would be my screen name that I use everywhere around the web (eg. `about.me/tschareck`). Another one would be more like `about.me/firstname.lastname`, so I can use it in more professional situations.

Is there any way to accomplish this, other than creating two profiles, one for my nickname, and one for my real name?

Comment: You want them to point to the same profile?

Comment: That would be most desirable, but is it doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, creating two separate profiles is your only option.

Comment: The longer I think about it, maybe it would make sense to have two profiles. One professional, one casual.

Comment: It certainly won't hurt to reserve your professional username for future use.